# Show tooltip when hovering over table cell border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a tooltip when the user hovers over the **left border** of the first `td` cell. My code is given below ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x1c3hxyx/1/)):

**HTML**

```
<table class="cart"> 
    <tr> 
        <th id="pos">Pos</th> 
        <th id="name">Product</th> 
        <th id="price">Price</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td>
              <span>New visual experience!</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>19.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <span>Inject music directly into your ears!</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>19.99</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table tr td{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.cart { width: 100%; }

td span {
    display: none;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
    cursor: arrow;
}

td:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have tried many ways, but the tooltip keeps appearing over the entire cell, and not over the left border like I want it. Can someone help please?

Comment: can you change any of the html markup?

Comment: I guess you can, so long as the tooltip appears over the border...I can't figure it out.

Comment: over the left border? you mean basiaclly right above the field you hover and then left align? just adjust these with `top` and `left`

Comment: Only when the cursor is hovering over the left border of the first cell, the tooltip should appear. Nowhere else.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "over the left border"? Could you explain? 

If I hover the cell from the top or right or bottom, the tooltip should not appear, and only appear if I enter the cell with the mouse cursor from the left?

Comment: basically yes. In the actual code, the left border has a different color and thickness from the rest. So if the border of the rest of the first cell and the rest is blue, the left border of the first cell is say, red and has thickness say 5 times more than the others. When you hover over that red border, the tooltip will appear

Comment: You mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/7mgt66cq/2/

Comment: No, that is what I am also getting - a tooltip wherever you move the cursor in the cell.

Comment: then Im tired and need to go bed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an absolutely positioned div with a width the size of the border (or slightly bigger) inside of the first `<td>` then use that to listen for the hover event.

https://jsfiddle.net/x1c3hxyx/4/